Error with Localtunnel + Prestashop with Virtual Host on port 80 (Mamp Pro)
I launch Localtunnel with this command
lt --port 80 --subdomain my-website --local-host my-website.test

but it opens the front-office on a white page with this text:
[Debug] This page has moved. 
Please use the following URL instead: http://my-website.loca.lt/it/

I already set domain and domain_ssl fields in xx_shop_url table with my-website.loca.lt
Where is the problem?
